# Meaning of 'state of affairs' in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading Times Of India editorial and ecountered the line:
 "However a series of developments have triggered anxiety on the **state of affairs** in the defence establishment currently, for reasons that go beyond corruption (but which may well be related to corruption)."

The article is read from 'Cleanup needed: Tyagi’s arrest should trigger systematic reform of the defence establishmen', dated 12 Dec, 2016(IST).
What is the meaning of state of affairs in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'state of affairs'** means 'the circumstances at a particular time', or more simply, 'the way things are at that time'.

In the context of your sentence, people are worried about the issues in the defence establishment at the moment, not just corruption, but other issues too.

Another familiar expression might be the [status quo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status%20quo), which means pretty much the same thing in Latin, and can be found in common usage.